# In AppDelegate how to detect if user is typing inside UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, appdelegate

I'm showing notification alert when app is active. In AppDelegate I'm handling push notification alert and action. I want to detect if user is typing in UITextView in a VC.

How to check it?

Following is the code snippet in **AppDelegate.swift**

```
switch application.applicationState {
case .active:
    if let topVC = currentNavInTab.visibleViewController as? ChatViewController {
        if topVC.user_is_typing { // How to detect if user is typing?
            return
        }
}
```

Comment: It would be a poor design to have your app delegate check what's going on in some view controller. Why do you need to do this? If you update your question with the actual problem you are trying to solve, you can get better answers.

Comment: Implement UITextView textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) delegate method inside your ChatViewController. Whenever user is typing this method will be invoked.

Comment: @rmaddy A user is on a VC and typing something in UITextView, a notification arrives and alert is shown. Usr taps on this alerts and navigates away from current VC. He will lose the typed message. To avoid this I want to stop any action on alert tap. I know that it's not a right way to do but I can't figure out any other way around this. Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: I actually shouldn't prevent the user to navigate away from your VC in the middle of a message (and I'm not really sure if you can prevent that). Trust me: as a user, if you try to prevent me from something I'm trying to do, I'm going to be pissed off. I would rather try to preserve state so when the user comes back the message is still there, that's the logical behavior.

Comment: @ManuMateos Tx I've also been thinking on preserving state. Will check it out.